# phpmyadmin does not have a mysql database

Tags: phpmyadmin, root

While using phpmyadmin, there is no mysql database.

When I run an SQL statement: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I get this error:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the PROCESS privilege for this operation
```

If I try to create a User, I can't because there is no mysql database users table.  If I try to create a database, it says I can't because I don't have user with advanced enough permissions.  I can't grant permissions to my passwordless user either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed it's old, but...
*Tested with phpMyAdmin 3.4.8*

Try this SQL using phpMyAdmin or other MySQL client you have:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

If you are able to list the databases with this, add the following line to your **config.inc.php**:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ShowDatabasesCommand'] = 'SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA';
```

Comment: Adding that line to my config file did it for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Why does phpmyadmin not reveal a mysql database?**

Because you are not logged in as the root user.  Perhaps you forgot that you set a root password when you were setting up mysql?  When you login to phpmyadmin with your root password, the following tables should be shown:

```
cdcol
data
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
webauth
```

These databases are auto-created when you install mysql may appear to be missing if you are logging in with the `user='admin' and password=''` credentials.  Or if you are logging in with a user with almost no rights to see or do anything.

**If you set your root password and forgot it, you can reset it**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

**If none of the above works:**

Blow away your mysql installation and do it again, this time pay attention to every installation step.  When it prompts you for a root password, either write it down on your hand or seriously question your decision to be a programmer who pays attention to detail.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because your user id doesn't have PROCESS privilege on the mysql server, I'm guessing it's a shared hosting?

If you are on windows platform, open your cmd, then navigate to your MySQL installation folder then type:

```
C:\ cd bin
C:\ mysql -uroot -p
-- enter your password
mysql> GRANT PROCESS ON your_db_name.* TO your_username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY your_password
```

Comment: how can i get through this problem?~i am just a newbie~

Comment: is this a development machine (do you own the machine) or shared hosting?

Comment: yes i am using phpmyadmin on my own laptop so not shared hosting i guess

Comment: login to your mysql as ROOT from command line and run: GRANT PROCESS ON your_db_name.* TO your_username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY your_password